# error installing mysql through homebrew cant connect to server through socket

Tags: mysql, ruby, terminal, homebrew

i am having an issue trying to connect to my mysql after installing it with homebrew...

im unsure what my next steps should be in order to troubleshoot/fix, i am going step by step with an online video tutorial and it doesnt offer me any advice.

the error:
`Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)`

location of installation:
`/usr/local/bin/mysql`

version:
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.10, for osx10.11 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Comment: does `brew doctor` raise any errors?

Comment: an error for node, but not related to mysql
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!

Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:
    node

Comment: try following those instructions

Comment: `sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/run/mysql_socket /var/mysql/mysql.sock` should help, MySQL places `mysql.sock` file on MacOS in weird places. If the above does not do the trick, try `find /usr/local/mysql -name mysql.sock` to locate the exact destination.

Comment: both list out no such file or directory

Comment: Is mysql running? `mysql.server start &` and `ps axffu|grep mysql`?

Comment: HEYYY it works now!!!! thank you!

Comment: I posted the answer for future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, make sure MySQL is up and running:

```
mysql.server start &
ps axffu|grep mysql
```

the above should print out the pid of running mysql process.

If this did not resolve an issue, try to locate the socket:

```
find /usr/local/mysql -name mysql.sock
find /var/mysql -name mysql.sock
```

and either update your configuration, or just create a symbolic link to it:

```
sudo ln -s FOUND_LOCATION /tmp/mysql.sock
```